# Grab specific line from a CURL response

Tags: php, bash, curl

I am working on WHMCS API and getting response in curl. I have to grab the value exactly from line 25. The response looks like this..

```
  array(1) {
    ["product"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(41) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(107)  // This is line 25
```

I have to grab the integer (and later use it as a variable in my bash script) that is under brackets. For the example above, it is 107.

Is there an easier way to a achieve this.

======

**This is my php file contains.**

```
<?php  
/**  
 * WHMCS Sample API Call  
 *  
 * @package    WHMCS  
 * @author     WHMCS Limited <development@whmcs.com>  
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) WHMCS Limited 2005-2016  
 * @license    http://www.whmcs.com/license/ WHMCS Eula  
 * @version    $Id$  
 * @link       http://www.whmcs.com/  
 */  
  
// API Connection Details  
$whmcsUrl = "https://my.whmcswebsite.net/";  
  
// For WHMCS 7.2 and later, we recommend using an API Authentication Credential pair.  
// Learn more at http://docs.whmcs.com/API_Authentication_Credentials  
// Prior to WHMCS 7.2, an admin username and md5 hash of the admin password may be used.  
$username = "something";  
$password = "something";  
  
// Set post values  
$postfields = array(  
    'username' => $username,  
    'password' => $password,  
    'action' => 'GetClientsProducts',  
    'domain' => 'fifi790.mydomain.net',  
    'responsetype' => 'json',  
);  
  
// Call the API  
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $whmcsUrl . 'includes/api.php');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));  
$response = curl_exec($ch);  
if (curl_error($ch)) {  
    die('Unable to connect: ' . curl_errno($ch) . ' - ' . curl_error($ch));  
}  
curl_close($ch);  
  
// Decode response  
$jsonData = json_decode($response, true);  

// Dump array structure for inspection 
var_dump($jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using sed

read line 25 from a file

```
line=$(sed '25!d' file)
```

remove everything before and after parentheses

```
echo ${line}  | sed 's/.*(//g' | sed 's/).*//g'
```